# Identify ALAssetsLibrary changes on app launch

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary

I am using the ALAssetsLibrary for retrieving photos and videos and am trying to improve my app performance in cases where the device has a large number of files.

To detect asset modifications while the app is running I am using the ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification to get a dictionary of changed assets, however, this will not detect changes when the app is fully closed (not just sent to the background), pictures are taken, and the app is opened again. In this case I am using:

```
dispatch_group_t dgroup = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

// Group enumerator Block (Go through each album)
void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) = [^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stopGroup) {

    // Successfully completed
    if (!group) {
        // Finished Enumeration

        LogTrace(@"Crawl successfully finished");

        return;
    }

dispatch_group_async(dgroup, queue, ^{

        // Asset enumerator Block (Go through each asset)
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:[^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stopAsset) {

            if(!result) {
                // Finished all assets in current group
                return;
            }

            // Hash and compare to value in database
                }
            }
        } copy]];

    });
    dispatch_group_wait(dgroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    LogTrace(@"Finished enumerating assets");

} copy];

// Group Enumerator Failure Block
void (^assetGroupEnumeratorFailure)(NSError *) = [^(NSError *error) {

    LogError(@"Upload Refresh Failed");

    LogError(@"Album Error: %@ - %@ - %@", [error description], [error localizedDescription], [error localizedRecoverySuggestion]);

    [self endOperation];

} copy];

// Sync all groups.
[self.assetsLibrary  enumerateGroupsWithTypes: ALAssetsGroupAll
                                   usingBlock: assetGroupEnumerator
                                 failureBlock: assetGroupEnumeratorFailure];
```

to enumerate all the assets, create a hash, and compare to values stored in a local SQLite database. This works, but can take a very long time to hash every asset.

Is there any modification date or additional metadata available that can help detect changes without the need to create a hash? I am aware of the creationDate property (ALAssetPropertyDate), but this does not change when the asset is modified. The rest of the meta data ([defaultRepresentation metadata]) doesn't seem helpful either.

Is there perhaps a way to attach custom meta data? The setImageData:metadata:completionBlock: looked promising, but only allows modification for assets created by the app to be modified. I was not able to find another solution in the documentation.

Any help would be appreciated.